# how to convert CSV or excel to PDF while keeping leading witespaces?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csvtotable

I am trying to convert csv to pdf and my column contains whitespaces like:

```
1,a,23,

2,   b, 34

3,    c,45

4, d,30

5,      e,67

6,  f,78
```

I tried:

`df.to_html()`

but it ignores the whitespaces.

Whitespace are important for this column as it represents hierarchy.

Comment: you can convert the whitespaces to `\t`, and then use df.to_html(), it will not trim the `\t`. from `to_html`'s document, I have not found any parameter related to whitespaces.

Comment: HTML alsways ignores whitespaces. You would have to use `&nbsp;` (`Non-Breaking SPace`) instead of every space. Or put text in `<pre></pre>` or `<code></code>` to respect whitespaces.